# Tensorflow sawtooth memory usage during training loop iteration

Tags: python, numpy, memory, tensorflow

I am training a neural network in a Python while loop which continues until some stopping condition is reached. I've noticed that when I train my network, I can see "sawtooth"/wave-like memory usage patterns, like this:

[image: sawtooth memory usage pattern]

I've managed to reproduce this using a much simpler example than my production model. Obviously this is somewhat different as I don't update parameters, but I believe it replicates the behavior I'm seeing.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def main(x_vals):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [500, 1000, 1000])

    rs = tf.reduce_sum(x)

    sess = tf.Session()

    v = sess.run(rs, feed_dict={x:x_vals})
    print(v)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x_vals = np.random.rand(500, 1000, 1000)
    while True:
        main(x_vals)
```

The size of the sawtooth seems to approximately scale with the size of the input data. Understandably, there appears to be one cycle per loop iteration.

What is happening here? Is Tensorflow copying over all of my data on each session evaluation? This isn't a problem per-se, but if I could avoid copying over my data on each training loop iteration (since my entire dataset fits in memory), I'd like to do that as I imagine the allocations are quite expensive. Have I diverged from best practices somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using feed_dict will typically copy the data. Recently there new functionality was added that will avoid the copy, but you have to make sure that your data is word-aligned, see discussion in
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9690

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my suspicion. What alternative approach to using feed_dicts would you recommend?

Comment: If you are already using feed_dict, then aligning the data as in the issue above may be easiest. Otherwise, you could rewrite your data pipeline to be purely TensorFlow (ie, using TensorFlow ops to read from files directly)

Comment: one more follow-up: do you know if it is possible to use tensor.proto (from core/framework/tensor.proto) instead of the example.proto to store my data as a .tfrecord? I use tensor protos with tensorflow serving currently so it may be easier to adopt my model to use that protocol buffer as a data receptacle.

Comment: Answering my own mini-question: it looks like this is possible (at least, tensor proto supports SerializeToString, which appears to be the method most important for replacing the example proto in the how_tos/reading_data/convert_to_records.py)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post a follow-up after a couple days of investigation. @Yaroslav pointed me in the correct direction, but there's a bit of color to the full answer.

One can limit some amount of memory allocation in each session by trying to avoid feed_dict by say, using a preloaded variable (if your dataset fits in memory). However, there's also some dynamic allocation done by the optimization computation graph, presumably to store gradients.

I've included code which demonstrates this. Here's a snippet of what the memory use looks like. On the left is repeated calling the preloaded function, while the right demonstrates repeatedly calling loaded_each_iteration.

[image]

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

A_shape = [100000, 3000]
b_shape = [100000, 1]

x_shape = [3000, 1]

def loaded_each_iteration(A_vals):
    A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, A_shape)

    b = tf.constant(np.random.rand(*b_shape), name='b', dtype=tf.float32)

    x = tf.Variable(np.zeros(x_shape, dtype=np.float32), name='x')
    diff = tf.matmul(A, x) - b
    cost = tf.nn.l2_loss(diff)

    train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.00001).minimize(cost, var_list=[x])

    sess = tf.Session()

    sess.run(x.initializer)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    while True:
        _, c = sess.run([train_op, cost], feed_dict={A:A_vals})
        print(c)


def preloaded(A_vals):
    A_init = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, A_shape)
    A = tf.Variable(A_init, trainable=False, collections=[], name='A', dtype=tf.float32)

    b = tf.constant(np.random.rand(*b_shape), name='b', dtype=tf.float32)

    x = tf.Variable(np.zeros(x_shape, dtype=np.float32), name='x')
    diff = tf.matmul(A, x) - b
    cost = tf.nn.l2_loss(diff)

    train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.00001).minimize(cost, var_list=[x])

    sess = tf.Session()

    sess.run([A.initializer, x.initializer], feed_dict={A_init:A_vals})
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    while True:
        _, c = sess.run([train_op, cost])
        print(c)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    A_vals = np.random.rand(*A_shape)
    while True:
        loaded_each_iteration(A_vals)
```